# MSBuild 3.5 from Hudson

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, hudson, hudson-plugins, hudson-plugin-batch-task

I am trying to set up MSBuild to compile a MS visual studio C++ project and running to some problem with include path. If I run MSBuild from command line, it builds successfully, but from within Hudson, the build failed because it can't find some include file.

I try to set the environment variable using setx, but that doesn't seem to help.

Here is the command that i used:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe c:\Path\To\Project.sln /t:Build /p:Platform="Win32";Configuration="Release" /v:diag

I tried using the plug in for MSBuild, as well as just call the command as batch command. Both failed.

Anyone can help?

ABS

---

### RESULT WHEN RUNNING IN THE COMMAND PROMP:

```
C:\hudson-service\jobs\SPOTR>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln /t:Build /p:Platform="Win32";Configuration="Release" /v:diag
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 3.5.30729.5420
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.5420]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 6/27/2013 10:43:41 AM.
Project "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln" on node 0 (Build target(s)).
Initial Properties:
_SolutionProjectCacheVersion = 3.5
_SolutionProjectConfiguration = Release|Win32
_SolutionProjectToolsVersion = 3.5
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
APPDATA = C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming
AspNetConfiguration = Release
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME = PSC6CKY6V1
ComSpec = C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
Configuration = Release
CUDA_PATH = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\
CUDA_PATH_V5_0 = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\
CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents = <SolutionConfiguration>.</SolutionConfiguration>
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK = NO
HOMEDRIVE = C:
HOMEPATH = \Users\User
INCLUDE = C:\boost\include\boost-1_52;C:\cudpp_bin_2.0\include;C:\curl-7.28.1\include;C:\cvblobslib;C:\opencv_242_bin\include;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include;C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\include;C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\include\gstreamer-0.10;C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\include\glib-2.0;C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\lib\glib-2.0\include;C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x8
6_64\include\libxml2;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include;
LIB = C:\boost\lib\lib32;C:\cudpp_bin_2.0\libs\win32;C:\curl-7.28.1\lib-static\win32;C:\cvblobslib\Win32\Debug;C:\cvblobslib\Win32\Release;C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\lib;C:\opencv_242_bin\libs\win32;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\lib\Win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
 Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\i386;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\\lib;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\lib;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\nvToolsExt\lib\Win32;
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER = \\PSC6CKY6V1
MSBuildBinPath = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
MSBuildExtensionsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild
MSBuildExtensionsPath32 = C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild
MSBuildNodeCount = 1
MSBuildProjectDefaultTargets = Build
MSBuildProjectDirectory = C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace
MSBuildProjectDirectoryNoRoot = hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace
MSBuildProjectExtension = .sln
MSBuildProjectFile = MYPROJECT.sln
MSBuildProjectFullPath = C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln
MSBuildProjectName = MYPROJECT
MSBuildStartupDirectory = C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT
MSBuildToolsPath = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
MSBuildToolsVersion = 3.5
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 12
NVCUDASAMPLES_ROOT = C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.0\
NVCUDASAMPLES5_0_ROOT = C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.0\
NVTOOLSEXT_PATH = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\nvToolsExt\
OS = Windows_NT
Path = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\libnvvp\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\opencv_242_bin\bin\x64;C:\tbb40_20120408oss\bin\ia32\vc9;C:\Program Files\Point Grey Research\Fl
yCapture2\bin64;C:\tbb40_20120408oss\bin\intel64\vc9;C:\opencv_242_bin\bin\win32;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009a\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009a\bin\win64;C:\Python27;C:\boost\lib64;C:\cudpp_bin_2.0\bin\win32;C:\cudpp_bin_2.0\bin\x64;C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\bin;C:\tbb41_20120718oss\bin\ia32\vc9;C:\tbb41_20120718oss\bin\intel64\vc9
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
Platform = Win32
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = x86
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 = AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 6
PROCESSOR_REVISION = 2d07
ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
PROMPT = $P$G
PSModulePath = C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME = Console
SolutionDir = C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\
SolutionExt = .sln
SolutionFileName = MYPROJECT.sln
SolutionName = MYPROJECT
SolutionPath = C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln
SystemDrive = C:
SystemRoot = C:\Windows
TargetFrameworkVersion = v3.5
TEMP = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP = C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN = PSC6CKY6V1
USERNAME = User
USERPROFILE = C:\Users\User
VS90COMNTOOLS = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\
windir = C:\Windows
windows_tracing_flags = 3
windows_tracing_logfile = C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log

Initial Items:
_SolutionProjectProjects


Building with tools version "3.5".
Target "ValidateSolutionConfiguration: (TargetId:322)" in file "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln" from project "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln":
Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; (('$(CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents)' == '') and ('$(SkipInvalidConfigurations)' != 'true')) was evaluated as (('<SolutionConfiguration>..</SolutionConfiguration>' == '') and ('' == 'true')).
Using "Message" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "Message" (TaskId:2)
  Building solution configuration "Release|Win32". (TaskId:2)
Done executing task "Message". (TaskId:2)
Done building target "ValidateSolutionConfiguration" in project "MYPROJECT.sln".: (TargetId:322)
Target "ValidateToolsVersions: (TargetId:323)" in file "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln" from project "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln":
Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(MSBuildToolsVersion)' == '2.0' and ('$(ProjectToolsVersion)' != '2.0' and '$(ProjectToolsVersion)' != '')) was evaluated as ('3.5' == '2.0' and ('' != '2.0' and '' != '')).
Done building target "ValidateToolsVersions" in project "MYPROJECT.sln".: (TargetId:323)
Target "Build: (TargetId:640)" in file "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln" from project "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln":
Task "MSBuild" skipped, due to false condition; (@(BuildLevel0) != '') was evaluated as ( != '').
Task "Message" skipped, due to false condition; (@(SkipLevel0) != '') was evaluated as ( != '').
Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; (@(MissingConfigLevel0) != '') was evaluated as ( != '').
Using "CallTarget" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "CallTarget" (TaskId:7)
Target "ValidateSolutionConfiguration" skipped. Previously built successfully.
Target "ValidateToolsVersions" skipped. Previously built successfully.
Target "teir1\teir2 (TargetId:324)" in file "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln" from project "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln":
Task "VCBuild" skipped, due to false condition; ( ('$(Configuration)' == 'Debug') and ('$(Platform)' == 'Win32') ) was evaluated as ( ('Release' == 'Debug') and ('Win32' == 'Win32') ).
Task "VCBuild" skipped, due to false condition; ( ('$(Configuration)' == 'Debug') and ('$(Platform)' == 'x64') ) was evaluated as ( ('Release' == 'Debug') and ('Win32' == 'x64') ).
Using "VCBuild" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "VCBuild" (TaskId:10)

  Locating vcbuild.exe: found at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\..\..\vc\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe". (TaskId:10)
  Command: (TaskId:10)
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\..\..\vc\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\ teir1\teir2\tier3.vcproj" "Release|Win32"  (TaskId:10)
  The "VCBuild" task is using "VCBuild.exe" from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\..\..\vc\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe". (TaskId:10)
  Microsoft (R) Visual C++ Project Builder - Command Line Version 9.00.21022 (TaskId:10)
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. (TaskId:10)
   (TaskId:10)
  Build started: Project: teir2, Configuration: Release|Win32 (TaskId:10)
  Compiling with CUDA Build Rule... (TaskId:10)
  "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\\bin\nvcc.exe"     -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\"  --machine 32 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin"    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi   /MD  "  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\\include" -maxrregcount=16 --ptxas-options=-v  --compile -o "Release/Cuda.cu.obj" Cuda.cu   (TaskId:10)

  Compiling... (TaskId:10)
  stdafx.cpp (TaskId:10)
  Compiling... (TaskId:10)
  StringUtils.cpp (TaskId:10)
  Teir3.cpp (TaskId:10)

  Compiling... (TaskId:10)
  dllmain.cpp (TaskId:10)
  Linking... (TaskId:10)
     Creating library C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\Release\Teir2.lib and object C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\Release\Teir2.exp (TaskId:10)
  Generating code (TaskId:10)
  Finished generating code (TaskId:10)
  Embedding manifest... (TaskId:10)
  Build log was saved at "file://c:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\teir1\teir2\Release\BuildLog.htm" (TaskId:10)
  Teir2 - 0 error(s), 3 warning(s) (TaskId:10)

Done executing task "VCBuild". (TaskId:10)
Task "VCBuild" skipped, due to false condition; ( ('$(Configuration)' == 'Release') and ('$(Platform)' == 'x64') ) was evaluated as ( ('Release' == 'Release') and ('Win32' == 'x64') ).
Done building target "teir1\teir2 " in project "MYPROJECT.sln".: (TargetId:324)
```

### RESULT WHEN RUNNING IN THE HUDSON:

```
C:\hudson-service\jobs\SPOTR\workspace>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln /t:Build /p:Platform="Win32";Configuration="Release" /v:diag 
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 3.5.30729.5420
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 2.0.50727.5420]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 6/27/2013 12:39:46 PM.
Project "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln" on node 0 (Build target(s)).
Initial Properties:
_SolutionProjectCacheVersion = 3.5
_SolutionProjectConfiguration = Release|Win32
_SolutionProjectToolsVersion = 3.5
ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData
APPDATA = C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming
AspNetConfiguration = Release
BASE = C:\hudson-service
BUILD_ID = 2013-06-27_12-39-35
BUILD_NUMBER = 384
BUILD_TAG = hudson-MYPROJECT-384
BUILD_URL = http://localhost:8080/configure/job/MYPROJECT/384/
CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME = PSC6CKY6V1
ComSpec = C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
Configuration = Release
CUDA_PATH = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\
CUDA_PATH_V5_0 = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\
CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents = <SolutionConfiguration>..</SolutionConfiguration>
EXECUTOR_NUMBER = 0
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK = NO
HUDSON_COOKIE = 0b8e2f57-e340-4697-be8c-94b8926dd1b5
HUDSON_HOME = C:\hudson-service
HUDSON_SERVER_COOKIE = 33ade14fb54aa2301680b4245b7a2cee
HUDSON_URL = http://localhost:8080/configure/
INCLUDE = C:\boost\include\boost-1_52;C:\cudpp_bin_2.0\include;C:\curl-7.28.1\include;C:\cvblobslib;C:\opencv_242_bin\include;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\include;C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\include;C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\include\gstreamer-0.10;C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\include\glib-2.0;C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\lib\glib-2.0\include;C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\include\libxml2;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include;
JOB_NAME = MYPROJECT
JOB_URL = http://localhost:8080/configure/job/MYPROJECT/
LIB = C:\boost\lib\lib32;C:cudpp_bin_2.0\libs\win32;C:\curl-7.28.1lib-static\win32;C:\cvblobslib\Win32\Debug;C:\cvblobslib\Win32\Release;C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\lib;C:\opencv_242_bin\libs\win32;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\lib\Win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\atlmfc\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0VCatlmfclibi386;C:Program FilesMicrosoft SDKsWindowsv6.0A\lib;C:Program FilesMicrosoft SDKsWindowsv6.0Alib;C:Program Files (x86)Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\lib;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\nvToolsExt\lib\Win32;
LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local
MSBuildBinPath = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
MSBuildExtensionsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild
MSBuildExtensionsPath32 = C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild
MSBuildNodeCount = 1
MSBuildProjectDefaultTargets = Build
MSBuildProjectDirectory = C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace
MSBuildProjectDirectoryNoRoot = hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace
MSBuildProjectExtension = .sln
MSBuildProjectFile = MYPROJECT.sln
MSBuildProjectFullPath = C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln
MSBuildProjectName = MYPROJECT
MSBuildStartupDirectory = C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace
MSBuildToolsPath = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5
MSBuildToolsVersion = 3.5
NODE_LABELS = master
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 12
NVCUDASAMPLES_ROOT = C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.0\
NVCUDASAMPLES5_0_ROOT = C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.0\
NVTOOLSEXT_PATH = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\nvToolsExt\
OS = Windows_NT
Path = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\libnvvp\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\opencv_242_bin\bin\x64;C:\tbb40_20120408oss\bin\ia32\vc9;C:\Program Files\Point Grey Research\FlyCapture2\bin64;C:\tbb40_20120408oss\bin\intel64\vc9;C:\opencv_242_bin\bin\win32;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009a\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009a\bin\win64;C:\Python27;C:\boost\lib64;C:\cudpp_bin_2.0\bin\win32;C:\cudpp_bin_2.0\bin\x64;C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86_64\bin;C:\tbb41_20120718oss\bin\ia32\vc9;C:\tbb41_20120718oss\bin\intel64\vc9;
PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
Platform = Win32
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = x86
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 = AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 6
PROCESSOR_REVISION = 2d07
ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
PROMPT = $P$G
PSModulePath = C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
SolutionDir = C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\
SolutionExt = .sln
SolutionFileName = MYPROJECT.sln
SolutionName = MYPROJECT
SolutionPath = C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln
SVN_REVISION = XXXX
SVN_URL = https://......
SystemDrive = C:
SystemRoot = C:\Windows
TargetFrameworkVersion = v3.5
TEMP = C:\Windows\TEMP
TMP = C:\Windows\TEMP
USERDOMAIN = WORKGROUP
USERNAME = PSC6CKY6V1$
USERPROFILE = C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile
VS90COMNTOOLS = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\
windir = C:\Windows
windows_tracing_flags = 3
windows_tracing_logfile = C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log
WORKSPACE = C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace

Initial Items:
_SolutionProjectProjects

Building with tools version "3.5".
Target "ValidateSolutionConfiguration: (TargetId:322)" in file "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln" from project "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln":
Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; (('$(CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents)' == '') and ('$(SkipInvalidConfigurations)' != 'true')) was evaluated as (('<SolutionConfiguration> .</SolutionConfiguration>' == '') and ('' != 'true')).
Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; (('$(CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents)' == '') and ('$(SkipInvalidConfigurations)' == 'true')) was evaluated as (('<SolutionConfiguration>.</SolutionConfiguration>' == '') and ('' == 'true')).
Using "Message" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "Message" (TaskId:2)
  Building solution configuration "Release|Win32". (TaskId:2)
Done executing task "Message". (TaskId:2)
Done building target "ValidateSolutionConfiguration" in project "MYPROJECT.sln".: (TargetId:322)
Target "ValidateToolsVersions: (TargetId:323)" in file "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln" from project "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln":
Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(MSBuildToolsVersion)' == '2.0' and ('$(ProjectToolsVersion)' != '2.0' and '$(ProjectToolsVersion)' != '')) was evaluated as ('3.5' == '2.0' and ('' != '2.0' and '' != '')).
Done building target "ValidateToolsVersions" in project "MYPROJECT.sln".: (TargetId:323)
Target "Build: (TargetId:640)" in file "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln" from project "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln":
Task "MSBuild" skipped, due to false condition; (@(BuildLevel0) != '') was evaluated as ( != '').
Task "Message" skipped, due to false condition; (@(SkipLevel0) != '') was evaluated as ( != '').
Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; (@(MissingConfigLevel0) != '') was evaluated as ( != '').
Using "CallTarget" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "CallTarget" (TaskId:7)
Target "ValidateSolutionConfiguration" skipped. Previously built successfully.
Target "ValidateToolsVersions" skipped. Previously built successfully.
Target "teir1\teir2: (TargetId:324)" in file "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln" from project "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\MYPROJECT.sln":
Task "VCBuild" skipped, due to false condition; ( ('$(Configuration)' == 'Debug') and ('$(Platform)' == 'Win32') ) was evaluated as ( ('Release' == 'Debug') and ('Win32' == 'Win32') ).
Task "VCBuild" skipped, due to false condition; ( ('$(Configuration)' == 'Debug') and ('$(Platform)' == 'x64') ) was evaluated as ( ('Release' == 'Debug') and ('Win32' == 'x64') ).
Using "VCBuild" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "VCBuild" (TaskId:10)

  Locating vcbuild.exe: found at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\..\..\vc\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe". (TaskId:10)
  Command: (TaskId:10)
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\..\..\vc\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe "C:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\ teir1\teir2\teir3.vcproj" "Release|Win32"  (TaskId:10)
  The "VCBuild" task is using "VCBuild.exe" from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\..\..\vc\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe". (TaskId:10)
  Microsoft (R) Visual C++ Project Builder - Command Line Version 9.00.21022 (TaskId:10)
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. (TaskId:10)
   (TaskId:10)
  Build started: Project: teir2, Configuration: Release|Win32 (TaskId:10)
  Compiling with CUDA Build Rule... (TaskId:10)
  "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\\bin\nvcc.exe"     -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\"  --machine 32 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin"    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /O2 /Zi   /MD  "  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\\include" -maxrregcount=16 --ptxas-options=-v  --compile -o "Release/Cudas.cu.obj" Cudas.cu   (TaskId:10)
.
  Compiling... (TaskId:10)
  stdafx.cpp (TaskId:10)
  Compiling... (TaskId:10)
  StringUtils.cpp (TaskId:10)
  Teir3.cpp (TaskId:10)
c:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\teir1\teir2\teir3.h(34): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2\opencv.hpp': No such file or directory
  Build log was saved at "file://c:\hudson-service\jobs\MYPROJECT\workspace\ teir1\tear2\Release\BuildLog.htm" (TaskId:10)
  tear2- 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (TaskId:10)
  The command exited with code 1. (TaskId:10)

Done executing task "VCBuild" -- FAILED. (TaskId:10)
Done building target " teir1\teir2" in project "MYPROJECT.sln" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:324)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the verbosity to diagnostic, so you have an enormous amount of information available to help you.  Comparing the logs from a successful build with a Hudson build, is there anything that stands out?  Go to the section where the VCXPROJ file is being built in both logs and see if Hudson is overriding local msbuild parameters with it's own.

You said that Hudson is complaining that it can't find some include file.  Are you able to post the exact error message (sans any sensitive information) when this occurs?

Comment: Nick, I posted the log output about. I looked through the log and there is nothing that jump out, maybe because i don't know what delta is important.